# Why is HTML table not styled when mobile website is compiled with PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm making a HTML5 mobile website using jquery mobile. It has five pages in a kind of wizard format and each page queries a web service to retrieve data. On the last page there is a HTML table which is predefined in the code which gets populated with the data from the web service. No rows are added dynamically just the placeholders in the table cells are populated with data.

This table has some styling defined in a stylesheet which looks fine when accessing with a desktop or mobile browser. However I am also compiling the mobile website with PhoneGap "Build" into native apps for Android, iOS, etc. This also works fine apart from on the last page, the table is not picking up the styling and is left completely un-styled.

You can see the page here: http:// m.freebets4all .com (remove the spaces). Just move through the wizard to the last page (selecting e.g. Betfred, Qualifying Bet and any of the Calculate buttons. The green table on the last page is completely unstyled when accessed via the Phone gap generated app.

Why is the table not styled when compiled with PhoneGap Build? Can anyone point me to some documentation which would explain this or have any experience with styling HTML tables under PhoneGap?

Here's the page in question, showing the table predefined in the html.

```
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phoneGap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/site.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Class.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/matcher-1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <div class="main">
        <div data-role="page" id="summary" data-title="Place Your Bets">
            <script>

                $('#summary').live('pagebeforecreate', function (event) {


                    var betSummary = new BetSummary($("#summaryTable"), localStorage.selectedBet);
                    setTimeout(function () { betSummary.displaySummary(); }, 1);
                    setTimeout(function () { $("summary").trigger('create') }, 2000);
                });

            </script>
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>
                    Place your bets...</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div class="content">
                    <div id="betInstructionsContainer" class="content">
                        <table class="matchedBet" data-role="table" id="summaryTable" data-mode="reflow">
                            <caption>
                                <p id="iDateLabel">
                                </p>
                                <p id="iMatchLabel">
                                </p>
                                <p id="iMarketLabel">
                                </p>
                            </caption>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Back
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Lay
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        <span id="iPlLabel" class="loss"></span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        <span id="iGainLabel" class="gain"></span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        <a id="iBookieLabel" title="" href="">
                                            <img id="iBookieImage" alt="10Bet" src="Images/logos/75x16/10Bet.gif">
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a id="iExchangeLabel" title="Click to go to the BetDaq website" href="http://www.freebets4allstage.co.uk/bookmaker/BetDaq/">
                                            <img id="iExchangeImage" alt="BetDaq" src="Images/logos/75x16/BetDaq.gif">
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th id="iOddsHeader">
                                        Odds
                                    </th>
                                    <td id="iBackOdds">
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="iLayOdds">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th id="iStakeLabel">
                                        Stake
                                    </th>
                                    <td id="iBackStake">
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="iLayStake">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th id="iRiskLabel">
                                        Risk
                                    </th>
                                    <td id="iBackRisk">
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="iLayRisk">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th id="iProfitLabel">
                                        Win
                                    </th>
                                    <td id="iBackProfit">
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="iLayProfit">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-position="fixed" data-role="footer">
                    <p class="gotosite">
                        <a href="http://www.freebets4all.com">Go to full website</a></p>
                    <p id="errorMessage">
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: are you sure the folder has your css files named Styles and not styles. cuz it's case sensitive.

Comment: That was it! Never though it would be such a simple solution. Definitely be careful of case when working with PhoneGap. How do I credit you with the answer?

Comment: then i'll write the answer in the answers section :)

Comment: A good server / filesystem should be case sensitive. So always be case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the folder has your CSS files named Styles and not styles, it's case sensitive.